# Use value in another column's previous row by group

Tags: python, pandas

**DATA**

```
Division    Name      start_date  
A           apple     2001-01-05
A           banana    2001-03-06
A           apple     2001-06-08
A           orange    2001-07-09
B           peach     2001-01-10
B           melon     2001-06-02
B           berry     2001-08-19
```

I need to create an end_date, which is the start_date of the next person in the same division. For the last person observed, there is no end_date, so I would just put today's date 2019-04-06.

**GOAL**

```
Division    Name      start_date    end_date
A           apple     2001-01-05    2001-03-06
A           banana    2001-03-06    2001-06-08
A           apple     2001-06-08    2001-07-09
A           orange    2001-07-09    2019-04-06
B           peach     2001-01-10    2001-06-02
B           melon     2001-06-02    2001-08-19
B           berry     2001-08-19    2019-04-06
```

I tried

```
data['end_date'] = data.groupby('Division')['start_date'].index+1
```

But got an error message:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'index' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) *division* and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) one row up.

```
df['end_date'] = df.groupby('Division').start_date.shift(-1)
```

Then just `fillna()` with today's date

```
df = df.fillna(datetime.date.today())

    Division    Name    start_date  end_date
0   A           apple   2001-01-05  2001-03-06
1   A           banana  2001-03-06  2001-06-08
2   A           apple   2001-06-08  2001-07-09
3   A           orange  2001-07-09  2019-04-06
4   B           peach   2001-01-10  2001-06-02
5   B           melon   2001-06-02  2001-08-19
6   B           berry   2001-08-19  2019-04-06
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you so much @RafaelC!!